# How to create a cron schedule for every 3 weeks starting from today or X date

Tags: cron

I'm needing to create a cron schedule for a Jira subscription to email out every 3 weeks from x date to line up with our sprints.

I could manually trigger this but ideally would like this automated.

-edited for current cron

0 0 8 1/21 * ? * this is as close as I've gotten but will only trigger on the 1rst of every month then 21 days after.

Comment: So question lack in information. Do you have cron option already in Jira and need the solution for that or You want to implement the Cron at OS level with bash script? Add more details and things you already tried.

Comment: Certainly, so there is a field with which you can enter a Cron expression the closest I can get to what I need is the following:

0 0 8 1/21 * ? *

But this will only do it from the start of the month, what I'm after is for it to trigger every 3 weeks after X date is this possible?

Comment: have you checked this https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/periodic-tasks-in-jira/qaq-p/494261

Comment: It doesn't do what i'm after sadly, although it contains several well written posts.